# Set the --rebase flag in Gitbox

Tags: git, rebase, pull, gitbox

A coworker of mine is using Gitbox to do all of his committing, pushing, etc., with Git. Right now when he pulls, his last commit message is destroyed and replaced with a merge commit message. It would be great if he could use the `--rebase` flag when pulling, but I can't a setting for it on the Gitbox website.

Answer (score 0):

In the Repository menu, the last item --- Settings... --- brings up a tabbed sheet.  The last tab is Advanced and is an editor over your actual Git settings for this repository.  Simply add a

```
rebase = true
```

line in the `[branch "master"]` section of the config file.

You can achieve the same effect for all branches by adding a `pull` section and putting the `rebase = true` line in there.

Make sure he understands the consequences of rebasing in a pull, and is prepared to fix conflicts once per commit instead of once total in a merge.